# QLocalServer - Help for beginner

Tags: c++, qt, this

I am new at Qt (and c++). I have a simple question:
What is wrong?

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QtNetwork/QLocalServer>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

  QLocalServer* x = new QLocalServer(this);
  return a.exec();
}
```

Thank for advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is this (pun intended):

```
QLocalServer* x = new QLocalServer(this);
```

`this` is not valid outside non-static class member functions. main() is not a member function, and thus `this` doesn't exist. You can pass NULL pointer instead, to signify that the object shall have no parent:

```
QLocalServer* x = new QLocalServer(NULL);
```

Don't forget to add the network module in your project file's `QT` variable. For example:

```
QT += OTHER_MODULES_YOU_USE_HERE network
```

Comment: I have tried "NULL" and I have got a different error: main.obj:-1: Error:LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __cdecl QLocalServer::QLocalServer(class QObject *)" (__imp_??0QLocalServer@@QEAA@PEAVQObject@@@Z) referenced in function main

Comment: You need to link against the QtNetwork module. You do that by adding `network` to the `QT` variable in your project file. I updated the answer.